# Handling the "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'true'" error when using pyecharts

Tags: python, jinja2, render

I'm trying to build a web page dashboard using pyecharts.  Rendering a single chart to an html file is successful.  However, if I use Tab or Page to add multiple charts to a single html file, I continue to get a "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'true" error.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Bar, Page, Tab


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["Person A", 'Person B', 'Person A', 'Person B'],
                    'Day': ['Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday'],
                   'Sales': [100, 350, 400, 500],
                   'Profit': [50, 175, 200, 250]})

group_by_name = df.groupby(by=['Name']).sum()[['Sales', 'Profit']]
group_by_day = df.groupby(by=['Day']).sum()[['Sales', 'Profit']]

barchart_by_name = (
    Bar()
    .add_xaxis(group_by_name.index.tolist())
    .add_yaxis('Sales', group_by_name['Sales'].round(0).tolist())
    .add_yaxis('Profit', group_by_name['Profit'].round(0).tolist())
    .set_global_opts(
        title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title='Fake Sales by Rep', subtitle='USD')
    )
)

barchart_by_day = (
    Bar()
    .add_xaxis(group_by_day.index.tolist())
    .add_yaxis('Sales', group_by_day['Sales'].round(0).tolist())
    .add_yaxis('Profit', group_by_day['Profit'].round(0).tolist())
    .set_global_opts(
        title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title='Fake Sales by Day', subtitle='USD')
    )
)

#barchart_by_name.render('Test.html') ##rendering a single chart works fine


#Create HTML file
tab = Tab(page_title='Dashboard Test')
tab.add(barchart_by_name, 'Fake Sales by Rep')
tab.add(barchart_by_day, 'Fake Sales by Day')
tab.render(Path.cwd() / 'Dashboard Test.html')
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.1\scratches\scratch_25.py", line 51, in <module>
    tab.render(Path.cwd() / 'Dashboard Test.html')
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyecharts\charts\composite_charts\tab.py", line 146, in render
    return engine.render(self, path, template_name, env, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyecharts\render\engine.py", line 76, in render
    template_name=template_name, chart=chart, path=path, **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyecharts\render\engine.py", line 55, in render_chart_to_file
    tpl = self.env.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyecharts\render\templates\simple_tab.html", line 11, in template
    {% if chart.use_custom_tab_css is not true %}
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 543, in _generate
    optimized=self.optimized)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 82, in generate
    generator.visit(node)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
    return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 754, in visit_Template
    self.blockvisit(node.body, frame)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 378, in blockvisit
    self.visit(node, frame)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
    return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 1157, in visit_If
    self.visit(node.test, if_frame)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
    return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 70, in new_func
    return f(self, node, frame, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 1497, in visitor
    self.visit(node.node, frame)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\visitor.py", line 38, in visit
    return f(node, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 70, in new_func
    return f(self, node, frame, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 1607, in visit_Test
    self.fail('no test named %r' % node.name, node.lineno)
  File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py", line 315, in fail
    raise TemplateAssertionError(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'true'
```

I also tried using the sample code for a simple page layout found on pyecharts site: https://gallery.pyecharts.org/#/Page/page_simple_layout.  This reproduces the same error but with a "no test named 'false'" error.  Is this a dependency issue?